# How does a compiler behave while reading memory in C program ? This is the following code I wrote to understand :

Tags: c, pointers, unsigned-integer

I've pointed p to integer n. While reading the value, I'm typecasting it to char, That says the compiler that he has to read only 1 byte of data. System is allocating 4 bytes for integer and 1 for char.
345 =  00000000 00000000 00000001 01011001 
So compiler reads last byte 01011001 = 89. 
I just wanted to know, if all compilers start reading from LSB? I Was wondering if we can get the output as MSB = 0;

```
void main()
{
  unsigned int n=345;
  char c = 't';

  void *p = &n;
  printf("%d",*((char *)p)); 

}

Output : 
89
```

Comment: I think you can get 0 with big endian machine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a big-endian architecture will print `0` instead of `89`.  You can see it here: https://godbolt.org/z/pLHMDd - PowerPC is big-endian and it gives zero as the result.

Comment: My bad.  Not being familiar with _godbolt_ readout, I misinterpreted what I saw.   Sorry.  (Will remove this comment once indicate  you've seen this.)

Answer (score 1):

*How does a compiler behave while reading memory in C program?*

A compiler is used during compile-time  to  convert source code into *machine code*.  Machine code (AKA executable  or binary file)  is used to run the program during run-time.

*I Was wondering if we can get the output as MSB = 0;*

The machine is either big or little endian, so it will process the data using its native architecture, but if you want to present data from one endian to the other, you can swap bytes.

Following is an adaptation of your code with some extra functions to illustrate byte swapping, and binary representation:

```
int main(void)
{
  unsigned int n=345;
  char c = 't';

  void *p = &n;
  printf("first byte before swap: %d\n",*((char *)p));

  //showing all bits for illustration
  printf("Binary - bytes before swap : %s\n\n", byte_to_binary32(n));

  //demonstration of byte swapping
  printf ( "\ndata before swapping : %04X" ,n);
  unsigned int new = swap(n);
  printf ( "\ndata after swapping : %04X\n" ,new);
  // end demo

  printf("Binary - bytes after swap: %s\n\n", byte_to_binary32(new));

  p = &new;
  printf("first byte after swap: %d\n",*((char *)p));

  return 0;

}

//unsigned 32 bit conversion
unsigned int swap (unsigned int data)
{ 
    unsigned int new = ((data>>24)&0xff) | // move byte 3 to byte 0
                                 ((data<<8)&0xff0000) | // move byte 1 to byte 2
                                 ((data>>8)&0xff00) | // move byte 2 to byte 1
                                 ((data<<24)&0xff000000); // byte 0 to byte 3;

    return new; 
}

const char *byte_to_binary32(long x)
{
    static char b[33]; // bits plus '\0'
    b[0] = '\0';
    char *p = b;  
    //unsigned long long z; required only if 64 bit conversion
    unsigned long z;//this is sufficient for 32 bit conversion
    for (z = 2147483648; z > 0; z >>= 1)       //2^32
    {
        *p++ = (x & z) ? '1' : '0';
    }
    return b;
}
```

Running this demo app will produce the following results:

[image]